# Android WebView E/SelfBrailleClient(): Failed to bind to service

Tags: android

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_main);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings set = webview.getSettings();


    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

but logcat show E/SelfBrailleClient

Comment: in android framework.